# Canvas Settings

Tags: facebook

Where do I find the canvas settings for a Facebook app.  I didn't create the application I was hired to fix a couple bugs, but I can't seem to find these GUI screen shots for Canvas settings that everyone is posting.

I need to update the Canvas URL from https:// to http://

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to application page, click on `Edit app` button, then in `App settings` section press `edit` link and you will see `Canvas URL` and `Secure Canvas URL` fields.